# How do I insert into a MySQL table only if it's empty?

Tags: mysql

**How do I insert into a MySQL table only if it's empty?**

I tried this (`WHERE` is not valid in that position):

```sql
INSERT INTO users(username, password, name, last_name, department, salary, age, email, enabled)
VALUES (
        # some values
            ),

       (
         # some values
           ),

         # even more rows 
        
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users);
```

ChatGPT suggested this:

```sql
INSERT INTO users (username, password, name, last_name, department, salary, age, email, enabled)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
    # values 
    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    # values 
    UNION ALL

    # ...
) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users);
```

StackOverflow has [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307164/execute-insert-if-table-is-empty) to a similar problem, but it's not fit for inserting multiple rows (as I understand it)

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (colname)
SELECT 'foo'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table)
```

It appears my MySQL version is 8.0.32 (as seen in `Help -> About Workbench`)

Comment: I have a Boot web app that handles database data. I want my app to be "oven-ready", so to speak, regardless of whether the required table exists (done) or whether it's empty or not (not done). So it would be nice if there was an SQL script that fills the table with sample rows in case no rows exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ROW constructor.

### DEMO

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, val INT);
```

```
INSERT INTO test
SELECT *
FROM (
  VALUES
  ROW(1,11),
  ROW(2,22)
) source_data
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM test
);
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 22 |

```
INSERT INTO test
SELECT *
FROM (
  VALUES
  ROW(3,33),
  ROW(4,44)
) source_data
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM test
);
```

> ```
> Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 22 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ih4LP3dG)

Comment: ROW constructor is described in [VALUES Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html) article.